# Asp Panel visible is true but panel is not displaying

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a content page which has 3 panels inside of update panel

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updateOfEmployee" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
   <ContentTemplate>
     <asp:panel ID="verificationOfEmployee" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" runat="server">
--some additional controls like textbox, dropdown list and validation control, visibility of all these controls set to true.
</asp:panel>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="emp_Address_Update" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
  <asp:Panel ID="emp_Addresss_Panel" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" runat="server">
--some additional controls like textbox, dropdown list and validation control, visibility of all these controls set to true.
</asp:Panel>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
   <asp:Panel ID="emp_Other_Details" BorderWidth="1px" BorderStyle="Solid" runat="server">
--some additional controls like textbox, dropdown list and validation control, visibility of all these controls set to true.
 </asp:Panel>code
```

In page load second panel `emp_Addresss_Panel.Visible = false`; and third panel `emp_Other_Details.Visible` = false; Inside click event from button one I was trying to set visible of second and third panel to true and visible of first panel to false but second and third panel is not visible in browser, I check visible property in a if statement for second panel and found second panel visible is already set to true but it's not appearing in browser. here is part of my code in click event of first panel.

```
verificationOfEmployee.Visible = false;
                        emp_Addresss_Panel.Visible = true;
                        if(emp_Addresss_Panel.Visible==false)
                        {
                            emp_Addresss_Panel.Visible = true;
                        }
                        emp_Other_Details.Visible = true;
```

Comment: You want to be VERY careful. If you set visible = false, then the panel is not ONLY hidden, but ALSO IS NOT SENT NOR RENDERED in the browser!!! - that means ajax, or client side js can't hide/show that information anymore. In such cases, I strong - but BEYOND STRONG recommend you hide/show using style="display:none" or display:in-line. So don't use visible to hide show - use/change the style since when visible = false, then that control is not only hidden - but it ALSO not rendered nor sent to the browser. That means any ajax, or client side code can't see, nor hide/show that panel.

Comment: Hello Albert, I already tried to use style display in page load, but result is same.

Answer (score 3):

By default, an AJAX post back of an `UpdatePanel` will not cause any content outside of it to update, including controls in another `UpdatePanel`. You have two solutions.

**1. Move every `Panel` to the same `UpdatePanel`**

```xml
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updateOfEmployee" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="verificationOfEmployee" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" runat="server">
            --some additional controls like textbox, dropdown list and validation control, visibility of all these controls set to true.
        </asp:Panel>            
        <asp:Panel ID="emp_Addresss_Panel" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" runat="server" Visible="false">
            --some additional controls like textbox, dropdown list and validation control, visibility of all these controls set to true.
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="emp_Other_Details" BorderWidth="1px" BorderStyle="Solid" runat="server" Visible="false">
            --some additional controls like textbox, dropdown list and validation control, visibility of all these controls set to true.
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

```cs
verificationOfEmployee.Visible = false;
emp_Addresss_Panel.Visible = true;
emp_Other_Details.Visible = true;
```

**2. Add Cross-`UpdatePanel` triggers**

*Note:* By adding an `AsyncPostBackTrigger` to the second `UpdatePanel`, it can be refreshed in the event from the first `UpdatePanel`. Note that your third `Panel` will not be updated as it is not in either `UpdatePanel`, or one of its own.

*Walkthrough:* [Cross-UpdatePanel Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers#walkthrough-cross-updatepanel-triggers)

```xml
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updateOfEmployee" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="verificationOfEmployee" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" runat="server">
            --some additional controls like textbox, dropdown list and validation control, visibility of all these controls set to true.
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Button ID="updateButton" runat="server" Text="Update" OnClick="updateButton_Click" />        
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="emp_Address_Update" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="emp_Addresss_Panel" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" runat="server" Visible="false">
            --some additional controls like textbox, dropdown list and validation control, visibility of all these controls set to true.
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="updateButton" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:Panel ID="emp_Other_Details" BorderWidth="1px" BorderStyle="Solid" runat="server" Visible="false">
    --some additional controls like textbox, dropdown list and validation control, visibility of all these controls set to true.
</asp:Panel>
```

```cs
protected void updateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    verificationOfEmployee.Visible = false;  // will render
    emp_Addresss_Panel.Visible = true;       // will render
    emp_Other_Details.Visible = true;        // will NOT render
}
```